# reiterate over the label's id using the following for loop and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four input radio buttons with four labels each having their own respective id (choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4)

I want to reiterate over the label's id using the following for loop and jquery. However, the choices: ["Ape", "Cat", "Wood", "Match"] are not appearing.  Can someone help me understand why it isn't working?

```
var allQuestions = [
    {
        question: "Take me out and scratch my head, I am now black but once was red.  What am I? ",
        choices: ["Ape", "Cat", "Wood", "Match"],
        correctAnswer: "Match"
    },
    {
        question: "My thunder comes before the lightning; My lightning comes before the clouds; My rain dries all the land it touches. What am I? ",
        choices: ["Sun-ray", "Ashes", "Volcano", "Lightning"],
        correctAnswer: "Volcano"
    },
    {
        question: "I'm the part of the bird that's not in the sky. I can swim in the ocean and yet remain dry. What am I? ",
        choices: ["Air", "Sponge", "Shadow", "Fire"],
        correctAnswer: "Shadow"
    }
];

for ( var i=0; i < allQuestions[0].choices.length; i++){
   $('#choice[i]').text(allQuestions[0].choices[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('#choice['+i+']').text(allQuestions[0].choices[i]);
```

instead of

```
$('#choice[i]').text(allQuestions[0].choices[i]);
```

Comment: I guess it should be `'#choice'+(i+1)`: *"I have four input radio buttons with four labels each having their own respective id (choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4)"*. You should also explain why this would solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you!! I dont know why i didn't think of it sooner..! I can just concatenate the i with a + symbol.  =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Your input radio button id's start from 1 so this solution works fine

```
$('#choice'+(i+1)).text(allQuestions[0].choices[i]);
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? Please explain the problem and why your answer solves it. Don't just post code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
for ( var i=0; i < allQuestions[0].choices.length; i++){
   $('#choice' + Number(i+1)).text(allQuestions[0].choices[i]);
   // i start from 0 so you need to plus 1 for it, #choice1, #choice2,...
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `Number` here?

Comment: To make sure it's not a string like 1 + 1 = 11.

Comment: If you want to prevent that the concatenation of `'#choice'` with `i` takes place first, use the grouping operator: `'#choice' + (i+1)`. Shorter to write and easier to execute.